# how to get from two table checked checkbox values using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have two tables, and in each table I have checked boxes. I am getting the
checked values from both, but I am saving in two different arrays and combining to into a single one.

Is there any way to get the checked checkbox values from both tables, but only from these tables?

#### My Attempt:

```
 var First = [];
 var Second = [];
 First = $("#table1 input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
     First[i] = $(this).val();
     return $(this).val();
 }).get();
 Second = $("#table2 input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
     Second[i] = $(this).val();
     return $(this).val();
 }).get();

 var subjes = First + Second;
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Can you post html also?

Comment: You're using the `.map()` func a bit wrong. `.map()` will create the array, all you do is return what you want in said array.

Comment: thanks for reply Here i am using two arrays i need to get those values in to single array

Comment: @Sadda-shutu I attempted to correct some of the grammar/spelling mistakes. Please double-check my re-phrasing to ensure that it is still asking what you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a selector that selects checkboxes in both tables before you map them :

```
var boxes  = $('input:checkbox:checked', '#MainContent_CBLFYSubjects, #MainContent_CBLSYSubjects'),
    subjes = $.map(boxes, function(el){
        return el.value;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply let me check